# Error al crear tabla SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo un problema al momento de crear mi tabla en MYSQL, ya que me manda error de sintaxis y que la versión no es la correcta. Quisiera que me pudieran apoyar para poder corregir este pequeño error.

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
  INDEX `FK_id_Equipo_idx` (`id_Equipo` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_id_Estadio_id' at line 17
SQL Code:

---

```
-- Table `Examen_bd`.`Partido`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Examen_bd`.`Partido` (
  `id_Partido` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `D_Partido` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
  `N_Juez_Linea2` VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL,
  `N_Juez_Linea1` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `Q_Goles_E1` INT NOT NULL,
  `Q_Goles_E2` INT NOT NULL,
  `N_Arbitro` VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL,
  `C_Resultado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_Campeonato` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_Estadio` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_Equipo` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_Partido`),
  INDEX `FK_id_Camponato_idx` (`id_Campeonato` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_id_Equipo_idx` (`id_Equipo` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `FK_id_Estadio_idx` (`id_Estadio` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_id_Camponato`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Campeonato`)
    REFERENCES `Examen_bd`.`Campeonato` (`id_Campeonato`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_id_Estadio`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Estadio`)
    REFERENCES `Examen_bd`.`Estadio` (`id_Estadio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_id_Equipo`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_Equipo`)
    REFERENCES `Examen_bd`.`Equipo` (`id_Equipo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Agredeceria muchos la ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soluciones:
1.Actualizar todo a la versión 8 o superior (recomendado)

O bien:

2 Quitar, donde quiera que aparezca, la palabra clave VISIBLE (o INVISIBLE si se diera un muy poco probable caso), y ejecutar de nuevo la sentencia, espero te funcione

Comment: Gracias, si funciono

Comment: De nada @FalconM98